# How to skip rows from a file until a specific string without using any input code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6, startswith

I have a txt file name 'test.txt' and want to skip the first rows until I get to the line with the string "~A".

At this line, I want to remove "~A" and create a dataframe with 3 columns named 'Stats1', 'Stats2' and 'Stats3' and the related values below.

Also, I do not want to use any 'input' function to skip rows while opening the file as I would like to generalize this to other files.

Here is how the file looks like:

### Text 1

### Text 2

### Text 3

### Text 4

### ~A  Stats1 Stats2 Stats3

### 1       2      3

### 6       6      7

### 8       9      3

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.startswith('~A'):
            columns = l.split()[1:]
            break
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=columns, sep=' ')
```

By looping through file `f` you consume unneeded lines.

Output:

```
>>> df
   Stats1  Stats2  Stats3
0       1       2       3
1       6       6       7
2       8       9       3
```

Comment: That is it, @Yevhen! That worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @LucasA please consider accepting the answer by checking the tick mark to the left of the answer